# xcode 4.2.1 build failed Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I followed the steps from this website http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode to deploy my app to jailbroken Ipad, but I received error after compile
error: can't exec '/usr/local/bin/ldid3.py' (Operation not permitted)

I set chmod +x to that file but still the same

I tried to execute "ldid3.py" in terminal and there's an error: invalid syntax

I'm using MacOS Lion 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.2.1

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time debugging this problem myself.  I don't know any Python, so it took me a while, but the solution is simple.  That ldid3.py script never writes the preferences to disk.  Simply add `f.flush()` after the `f.write(...)`.  I hope that helps.